# the existence of an extended holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: \Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ be defined and continuous on $\Omega$,
> $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open. Assume that $f$ is holomorphic on
> $\Omega\setminus A$, $A$ is a discrete set that has no limit points on
> $\Omega$. Prove that $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function $g$
> on $\Omega$, i.e there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$
> s.t $g(z)=f(z)\quad\forall z\in\Omega\setminus A$.

I know a theorem that's kinda similar to this problem:

> Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on $0<|z-z_0|<R$. If $z_0$ is a [removable
> point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) of $f$ then $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function $g$ on
> $|z-z_0|<R$ s.t $f(z)=g(z)$ on $0<|z-z_0|<R$.

Sadly, I have no idea how to start to deal with this problem. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A$ was a single point, or a finite set, do you know how to solve the problem in that case? Or phrased better: do you see how to apply your quoted result?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I don't think so since $\Omega$ is a domain, not a circle itself

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is an open set, the around every point, you can find a disk containing it and contained within $\Omega$.